# Problems installing Stepmania on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation

I'm trying to install Stepmania, following these instructions: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2138685

I finally figured out how to install libpng1.5.15 thanks to someone on here. Now I'm having trouble with the final step. I extracted the .tar.bz2 file to my desktop, and did the "cd Desktop/stepmania" command. The next command is the one that gives me trouble, though: "./stepmania"

When I enter "./stepmania" it gives me an error message, and a crash info txt file. I'll copy and paste all of that.

```
me@laptop:~/Desktop/stepmania$ ./stepmania
StepMania v5.0 beta 1a
Compiled 20121229 @ 14:24:04 CET (UTC+01:00) (build 0)
Log starting 2013-09-14 13:29:44
Loading window: gtk
OS: Linux ver 030500
Crash backtrace component: x86 custom backtrace
Crash lookup component: dladdr
Crash demangle component: cxa_demangle
Runtime library: glibc 2.15
Threads library: NPTL 2.15
libavcodec: 0x352300 (3482368)
TLS is available
/////////////////////////////////////////
WARNING: ReadFile(Save/ThemePrefs.ini): No such file or directory
/////////////////////////////////////////
ALSA: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version 1.0.25.
ALSA Driver: 0: HDA Intel PCH [PCH], device 0: VT1802 Analog [VT1802 Analog], 1/1 subdevices avail
ALSA Driver: 0: HDA Intel PCH [PCH], device 2: VT1802 HP [VT1802 HP], 1/1 subdevices avail
ALSA Driver: 0: HDA Intel PCH [PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0], 1/1 subdevices avail
ALSA: dsnd_pcm_hw_params_set_access: Invalid argument
Couldn't load driver ALSA-sw: SetHWParams failed
Sound driver: pulse
/////////////////////////////////////////
WARNING: Error opening serial port for lights. Error:: 2 No such file or directory
/////////////////////////////////////////
Lights driver: PIUIO
Lights driver: SystemMessage
Lights driver: Export

(stepmania:19700): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_style_detach: assertion `style->attach_count > 0' failed
Video renderers: 'opengl'
Display: :0.0 (screen 0)
X server vendor: The X.Org Foundation [1.13.0.0]
Server GLX vendor: SGI [1.4]
Client GLX vendor: Mesa Project and SGI [1.4]
/////////////////////////////////////////
WARNING: X11 Protocol error BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation) (11) has occurred, caused by request 154,3, resource ID 39
/////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////
WARNING: X11 Protocol error GLXBadContext (172) has occurred, caused by request 154,3, resource ID 79691781
/////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////
WARNING: X11 Protocol error GLXBadContext (172) has occurred, caused by request 154,5, resource ID 79691781
/////////////////////////////////////////
ptrace failed: Operation not permitted
ptrace failed: Operation not permitted
ptrace failed: Operation not permitted
ptrace failed: Operation not permitted
ptrace failed: Operation not permitted

StepMania 5 has crashed.  Debug information has been output to

    /tmp/crashinfo.txt

Please report a bug at:

    http://ssc.ajworld.net/sm-ssc/bugtracker/

Killed
```

And then the crashinfo.txt says:

```
StepMania v5.0 beta 1a crash report (build 0, 20121229 @ 14:24:04 CET (UTC+01:00))
--------------------------------------

Architecture:   Unix
Crash reason:   Segmentation fault - address not mapped at 0x000000000000000c
Crashed thread: Main thread

Checkpoints:
Thread: Main thread
        Profile.cpp:1427 
        Profile.cpp:1504 
        Profile.cpp:1608 
        Profile.cpp:1663 
        Profile.cpp:1697 
Thread: Decode thread
Thread: Music thread
Thread: Worker thread (MemoryCardWorker)
Thread: Worker thread (/@mc1int/)
Thread: Worker thread (/@mc2int/)

Thread: Main thread
00007fdfb9de2cc0: 
00007fdfbe5264d4: 
00007fdfbe5264d4: 
00007fdfbe523f2c: 
0000000000ac7f3f: SetupExtensions() 

Static log:
StepMania v5.0 beta 1a
Compiled 20121229 @ 14:24:04 CET (UTC+01:00) (build 0)
Log starting 2013-09-14 13:29:44
Loading window: gtk
OS: Linux ver 030500
Crash backtrace component: x86 custom backtrace
Crash lookup component: dladdr
Crash demangle component: cxa_demangle
Runtime library: glibc 2.15
Threads library: NPTL 2.15
libavcodec: 0x352300 (3482368)
TLS is available
WARNING: ReadFile(Save/ThemePrefs.ini): No such file or directory
ALSA: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version 1.0.25.
ALSA Driver: 0: HDA Intel PCH [PCH], device 0: VT1802 Analog [VT1802 Analog], 1/1 subdevices avail
ALSA Driver: 0: HDA Intel PCH [PCH], device 2: VT1802 HP [VT1802 HP], 1/1 subdevices avail
ALSA Driver: 0: HDA Intel PCH [PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0], 1/1 subdevices avail
ALSA: dsnd_pcm_hw_params_set_access: Invalid argument
Couldn't load driver ALSA-sw: SetHWParams failed
Sound driver: pulse
WARNING: Error opening serial port for lights. Error:: 2 No such file or directory
Lights driver: PIUIO
Lights driver: SystemMessage
Lights driver: Export
Video renderers: 'opengl'
Display: :0.0 (screen 0)
X server vendor: The X.Org Foundation [1.13.0.0]
Server GLX vendor: SGI [1.4]
Client GLX vendor: Mesa Project and SGI [1.4]
WARNING: X11 Protocol error BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation) (11) has occurred, caused by request 154,3, resource ID 39
WARNING: X11 Protocol error GLXBadContext (172) has occurred, caused by request 154,3, resource ID 79691781
WARNING: X11 Protocol error GLXBadContext (172) has occurred, caused by request 154,5, resource ID 79691781
Language: en
Current renderer: OpenGL
Theme: default

Partial log:
00:00.159: Applying defaults for OpenGL.
00:00.159: Video renderers: 'opengl'
00:00.159: RageDisplay_Legacy::RageDisplay_Legacy()
00:00.159: Display: :0.0 (screen 0)
00:00.160: X server vendor: The X.Org Foundation [1.13.0.0]
00:00.163: Server GLX vendor: SGI [1.4]
00:00.163: Client GLX vendor: Mesa Project and SGI [1.4]
00:00.257: WARNING: X11 Protocol error BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation) (11) has occurred, caused by request 154,3, resource ID 39
00:00.257: WARNING: X11 Protocol error GLXBadContext (172) has occurred, caused by request 154,3, resource ID 79691781
00:00.257: WARNING: X11 Protocol error GLXBadContext (172) has occurred, caused by request 154,5, resource ID 79691781

-- End of report
```

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu/Linux, so I'm still trying to figure it out. I don't understand most of it so far. Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

Try Install in this way,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phantom10111/stepmania

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install stepmania
```